# Troubleshooting mapping

Tags: key-bindings

I have the following in my `vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <C-J> o<Esc>k$
nnoremap <C-K> O<Esc>j$
```

The bottom mapping works as expected, but `c-j` now produces the same effect as `i` (which is really dumb). To troubleshoot, I tried:

```
verbose map c-j 
" UPDATE: the above is wrong. Instead use:
verbose map <c-j> 
verbose map <buffer>
```

The top command returns <strike>nothing</strike> (see last update), and the bottom nothing relevant. How can I find out what's wrong?

**Update.** Someone said this is a duplicate of [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/disable-esc-but-keep-c), but I don't understand how. For what it's worth, I got the idea for the mapping from the [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_newline_without_entering_insert_mode), so it must've worked for some people. In fact, it was working for me, too, before it stopped. Also, according to the help, `c-j` is supposed to be the same as `c-n` and `<nl>`, but that's not the case here as I said earlier. It behaves like `i`, and I would like to know how to figure out why.

**Update II.** The mapping now works fortuitously after the following change. If there's a decent explanation, I'll accept it as answer. Otherwise, I'm happy enough to get this to work.

```
" old
" nnoremap <CR> :noh<CR><CR>
" new
nnoremap <CR> :noh<return>
```

**Update III.** It's not working again, but I now realize that my `verbose map` syntax above is incorrect. The correct syntax gives me something to work with. Thanks all.

Comment: `<C-J>` is newline. Use another key for this mapping.

Comment: @muru See my edit. I don't see why it's a duplicate. For what it's worth, I even managed to map `<cr>`, with great results. This should work and has worked. Now that it doesn't, I want to find out why.

Comment: I didn't say you can't map `<c-j>`, I suggested using another key. In any case, if I add `nnoremap <C-J> o<Esc>k$` and `nnoremap <CR> :noh<CR><CR>` to my vimrc, `<c-j>` works as expected. As you say: "fortuitously". Further, if you use `nnoremap <CR> :noh<return>`, and the cursor still moves down a line, I'd be very surprised. Since `verbose map` was silent, `<c-j>` was unmapped later on somewhere in your config. Have a look at any plugins you use. In any case, see: [How do I debug my vimrc file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file)

Comment: also worth looking: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-to-debug-a-mapping

Comment: I have just tried your mapping of `<c-j>` with both forms of the `<CR>` mapping and it seem to work in both cases so I'm not sure that was the real cause of your problem.

Comment: I would suggest a different key.There are also a few posts about inserting blank lines that you may want to check out: [how to insert a newline without leaving normal mode](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3875/778), [Vim command to insert blank line in normal mode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6765211/438329), [http://stackoverflow.com/q/16359878/438329](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16359878/438329)