# What is the fastest way to yank with a line break?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Let say I have a simple line

```
hell<cursor>o
```

What is the fastest way to yank this line and paste to a result like this?

```
hello

hello
```

I am currently doing this:

```
yy # To yank this line
p # Paste on next line
O # To insert and add a line above the pasted line
```

But doing so I will end up in Insert Mode. How can I stay in normal mode for all this?

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of [How to insert a newline without leaving normal mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3875), or at least it is very related. This the mapping from this question you'd end up with `Y<leader>op`

Comment: Good find. I wouldn't have expected it to be such a popular Q (and have so many As).

Comment: Surprisingly, it doesn't look like my answer appears there. Closest I found is "you can yank `yy` an empty line and then pasted `p` for below cursor and `P` for above the cursor". I'm not sure whether that means `Y2pD` is kinda clever or sorta tacky. :D

Comment: Map normal mode enter to insert a blank line

Comment: Looking from a different perspective... If you didn't want to end up in Insert Mode because `ESC` is too far away, `Ctrl+C` is an alternative and more convenient way of returning to the Command mode.

Comment: @raylight C-c is emphatically _**not**_ equivalent to Escape; too many people think they are equivalent. Here's a simple demonstration of why not: launch `vim -Nu NONE`. Now see what the difference is between `5ii<esc>` and `5ii<C-c>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim golf? :)

How about

```
Y2pD
```

It's perhaps a little contrived to create two new `hello` lines only to delete one but trying to avoid Insert mode is also a bit contrived when you're actually, you know, inserting new text (the blank line). ;)

Comment: What magic is this!

Comment: This is terrific! (Although not actually any fewer keystrokes than `YpO<Esc>`)

Comment: @Rich `YpO<Esc>` is good too!

Answer (score 2):

There is also the [unimpaired plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) that give mappings in normal mode for putting in blank lines (among other `[` and `]` base mappings). I never would have thought I'd use them, but I do constantly - these in particular are burned into my fingers:

> There are linewise mappings. `[<Space>` and `]<Space>` add newlines before
> and after the cursor line. `[e` and `]e` exchange the current line with
> the one above or below it.

So you could do:

```
Yp[<Space>
```

Also:

> The . command works with all operator mappings, and will work with the > linewise mappings as well if you install [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat).